# US states and cities distance from eachother

Tags: geolocation, dataset, distance

I'm building a web based application to determine a value, which consists the calculation of the distance between X city to Y city (US).

Is there a data resource to pull that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latitude and longitude of your cities from a map API.  I use Yahoo's because their terms of service fit better with my needs, but the Google API is certainly a good choice as well.

The Yahoo API is described here

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Once you have the latitude and longitude, you can find the distance either using a fairly straightforward formula

[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

or with another API:

http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/maps/classreference/com/yahoo/maps/api/utils/Distance.html